# DI and constructor parameters count

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I use dependency injection for my MVC layered application. I faced with the problem when my business logic classes require too many dependencies (5+ interface parameters). As a result class constructor becomes wide and ugly. Is it ok for DI pattern or not? I can split my business class into less complex ones (and number of parameters becomes acceptable), but then number of parameters inside controllers will increase (as they will require more buisness objects).

How to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor over-injection is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) because it is often an indication of a violation of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). In other words, if a class has many dependencies it is an indication that it has multiple responsibilities; it does too much. Classes that do too much are hard to understand, test and maintain.

I think you are on the right track by splitting up your business logic classes. A pattern that I found very effective in this is giving each business logic class one single (public) method and let them implement one single use case. Take a look at the [command/handler pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) as an example of this.

But now you are moving the problem up to your controllers, but just as with classes in your business layer, the same holds for controller classes in your presentation layer: if they have many dependencies, they probably have a lot of code and become a maintenance problem.

But just as you split up your BL classes, you can do the same for your controllers. Nobody said that controllers should have many action methods with a lot of code. You can create multiple controllers that use the same view model and the same view in ASP.NET MVC. This view should than be placed in the Shared folder and named clearly so that MVC can find the view. I found this to be not so pleasant in all cases while working with ASP.NET MVC, but don't let your presentation framework dictate your design. Follow the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29); the rest follows from that.

Another option is to extract [aggregate services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) out of your controllers. Take a good look at the code in your controllers. You will often see that a whole group of dependencies is used in combination. Extract those dependencies with the code that uses them into a new class and inject that class into the controller's constructor instead. If your class is too big, you are probably missing an abstraction. Finding the right abstraction is often not easy, and it often takes me some time to get to the right name. You'll see me changing the name of such aggregate service a few times, moving logic in and out of it, until it feels right. Don't be scared to experiment with this.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!